# plot text truncates when saving as pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, pdf-generation

My plots when saved as pdf suffer from getting truncated, see example below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

pp <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(mpg > 13, mpg < 20) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = cyl)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = hp), vjust = -0.5)


pdf(file = "test.pdf", paper = "A4r"))
pp + pp + plot_layout(ncol = 1)
dev.off()
```

The plot prints fine in rstudio window, everything shows-up nicely.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: try using `ggsave` instead? I've found the scaling behaviour of `ggsave` better than `pdf`

Comment: I cannot install patchwork on my system.. but if i use library(gridExtra); pdf(file = "test.pdf", paper = "A4r") ; grid.arrange(pp,pp,ncol=1) ; dev.off() , it is ok

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked. For anyone who came looking for an answer please use `ggplot2::ggsave` and in it set `scale = 1.15` and play around with the value, to make the plot fit, increase the value.